# Is java Purely Object Oriented?

Tags: java

We are saying that java is not purely object oriented since primitive data types are not objects.But in below code how object is holding primitive data type?

```
public class Test{

    public Object meth(Object obj){
        System.out.println(obj instanceof Object);//It prints true
        System.out.println("Value = "+obj);//It prints "Value = 1"
        return obj;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        System.out.println(new Test().meth(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: See documents on `autoboxing` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html  Java has an integer class.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the phenomenon you're observing is due to Java's autoboxing feature. But I don't think it's very useful to talk about languages being "purely object-oriented" or not; there's no real definition for what being "object-oriented" even means, exactly, so it's not really possible to say whether a language exactly matches that definition or not.

Answer (score 8):

It's called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).  Basically, the Java compiler converts primitive data types into objects  for you when you use them in a context that requires them to be objects.

Answer (score 4):

Since there are 8 primitive types in Java it is not purely object oriented language. But primitive types make Java more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Because primitive types are auto-boxed(in java terms) to objective types.
For example, int are wrapped in a Integer Object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right...Java is not pure Object oriented because  it supports Primitive datatype such as int, byte, long... etc, to be used, which are not objects...

Above concept this called ***autoboxing***.

> **Autoboxing:** Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes

Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 2):

Java is Purely Object Oriented because every thing in Java is treated as an Object. However, Java is not purely Object Oriented because still it supportd primitive data types that violates the OOPs philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

ava is not pure Object oriented because it supports Primitive datatype such as int, byte, long its True , but we Have Classes like Integer Character classes in java , the conversion from primitive to these classes when done implicitly is called as autoboxing. this can be done Explicitly too .

Answer (score 0):

Java Is Not pure object oriented language due to following reasons.

1. Java supports primitive data types.
2. Java supoort static and these belong to class not to object.
3. java supports enumerations.

And as per OOP, Everything should be an object.

Comment: Actually, each class is an object, with the class of `java.lang.Class` being the same `Class` typed object. Of course, primitives break the purity by a large margin, regardless of autoboxing.

Answer (score 0):

In your context it is **called auto boxing** because you are just passing a non primitive value to a Object argument it will automatically convert it in object type.

Answer (score 0):

Because if using primitives java is not purely object oriented. For further more details follow this [link](http://vhariprasath.blogspot.in/2014/04/is-java-purely-object-oriented.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java is not purely object oriented programming language
to satisfy a programming language is object oriented then it satisfy
oops concepts
Encapsulation/Data Hiding
Inheritance
Polymorphism
Abstraction
All predefined types are objects
All operations are performed by sending messages to objects
All user defined types are objects.
these are the things . some says that java support primitive data type like int ,float so its not object oriented but eventhough it is based on the Wrapper class INTGER ,FLOAT 
the things java suppourt static keyword its doesnt not follow the oops so java is not pure object oriented language

Answer (score 0):

No It is not because data types are not classes unlike in c# where data types are classes .yes wrapper classes are introduced later in java but there is concept of autoboxing and out boxing which makes the situation complex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Java is not purely object oriented as it contains primitive data types which are not objects. In case of your scenario you are passing an int value to the function. The reason behind this it is working is that **autoboxing**.
The following provided link might help to understand autoboxing well.
[click here](https://coderanch.com/t/417622/certification/Golden-Rules-widening-boxing-varargs)